# Python 2,7 Dictionary Advice

Tags: python, dictionary

I do not use dictionary objects often in Python. I've been working on a script that is going to require me to use a dictionary to store dynamically created list'esque information. How can I append a value to a list of values belonging to one key in a dictionary in Python? Is this possible? I would hope to be able to create this type of information from which I could pull later...

```
dict = {'PhysicalDrive0': '0', '1', '2', 'PhysicalDrive1': '0', '1'};
dict[PhysicalDrive0].append(3)
dict[PhysicalDrive1].append(2)
print dict[PhysicalDrive0]
<0, 1, 2, 3>
print dict[PhysicalDrive1]
<0, 1, 2>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers everybody! Every answer was relevant and helpful. I chose the one most relevant to my script/issue syntactically. Again many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list as value, list will allow you to append new items:

```
>>> dic = {'PhysicalDrive0': ['0', '1', '2'], 'PhysicalDrive1': ['0', '1']}
>>> dic['PhysicalDrive0'].append('3')
>>> dic['PhysicalDrive1'].append('2')
>>> dic
{'PhysicalDrive1': ['0', '1', '2'], 'PhysicalDrive0': ['0', '1', '2', '3']}
```

To append to a value to a missing key you can use `dict.setdefault`, if the key is already present then it'll append value to the already present list otherwise creates a key with an empty list and then appends the value to it.

Demo:

```
#creates a new key PhysicalDrive3' and appends a value to it.
>>> dic.setdefault('PhysicalDrive3', []).append('3')
>>> dic
{'PhysicalDrive1': ['0', '1', '2'], 'PhysicalDrive0': ['0', '1', '2', '3'], 'PhysicalDrive3': ['3']}

>>> dic.setdefault('PhysicalDrive1', []).append('5')
>>> dic
{'PhysicalDrive1': ['0', '1', 2, '5'], 'PhysicalDrive0': ['0', '1', '2', 3], 'PhysicalDrive3': [3]}
```

Comment: @Stephan for some reason [community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is rejecting your edits.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at `collections.defaultdict` if you can't simply store the value as a list literal...:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)    
dd['Drive1'].append(3)
dd['Drive2'].append(6)
dd['Drive1'].append(2)

# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Drive2': [6], 'Drive1': [3, 2]})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict = {'PhysicalDrive0': ['0', '1', '2'], 'PhysicalDrive1': ['0', '1']}
```

This should work as stated.  The value stored in the dictionary is a list - which you can handle as normal.

This, of course, means that you can access the items of the list as:

```
dict['PhysicalDrive0'][0]
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid, the value half of your key-value needs to be a single item, it can be a list, however so you could say `'PhysicalDrive0':['0','1','2']`

You would then append to that key-value pair in the dictionary by saying `dict['PhysicalDrive0'].append('3')`